# Dateparser returns NoneType for all type of date formats

Tags: python, dateparser

it's all in the title, I tried different versions of dateparser (1.1.8, 1.0.0,...), it always returns *None*

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('12/12/12')
>>> print(dateparser.parse('12/12/12'))
None
>>> dateparser.__version__
'1.0.0'
>>> dateparser.parse(u'Le 11 Décembre 2014 à 09:00')
>>> print(dateparser.parse(u'Le 11 Décembre 2014 à 09:00'))
None
>>>
```

Please can anyone help with this issue

Comment: I tested both with version 1.0.0 and 1.1.8 and I can't reproduce your issue: `print(dateparser.parse('12/12/12'))` -> `2012-12-12 00:00:00`

Comment: I check with dateparser version - '1.1.8', your code works! Check with that version